Scoot airlines charged me $1,625 for one extra luggage at the airport. Is it legit?
I flew from Krabi to Jakarta with Scoot. I had to buy one extra luggage at the airport because I couldn't do it online. The airlines charged me $1,625 for one 23-kg luggage. I thought this is a mistake but at that time I had no choice so I paid.
I sent an email to their office and was told that is the correct amount. I bought extra luggage before from Jakarta to Toronto, and it cost me $250.

The last minute extra luggage may really cost a lot. Try to buy it in advance (and so you see: try harder). Else try to go to airport much earlier. In last hour, the airline may have sold the excess cargo (and the airline do not take commercial risk so we passengers pay.

Did you get a receipt? Does the receipt specify how the fee was calculated (by weight?)?

Related question

Are you sure the amount is in USD and not THB or some other currency? Did you already have checked bags? If so, what was the purchased number and weight and the actual number and weight?

What's the currency of that amount?

Did you pay cash or did you use a payment card?  If they charged 60,000 baht instead of 6,000 baht and they refuse to correct it then you may be able to dispute the transaction with the card issuer.

Often it's better to not pack a bag.  Instead, buy what you want at your destination. You help the local economy, don't look like a tourist, and can give everything you aren't wearing to charity before you return home.

@EndAntisemiticHate: But note that traveling without the expected quantity of luggage is suspicious to immigration authorities and may get you flagged for questioning or even denied entry.

@BenVoigt That's a good point. Thanks.  Does immigration have access to the number of pieces and weight of luggage passengers checked and are carrying aboard?  If so, I could see low amounts leading to possibly being flagged. But are there many cases of passengers being denied entry (especially when the honest response isn't complicated and can be quickly verified)?

Scoot's fare chart is here: https://www.flyscoot.com/en/plan/scoot-fees-chart For one extra bag from Krabi to Jakarta this should have been around 6000 Thai Baht or $165.00 US, which seems off by a factor of 10.
Of course, this all depends on what the conditions of your original tickets are and what else you checked or services you bought. I suggest carefully reading the receipt which should list the individual charges (if its more than one) and what tarifs applied.

Note that it says “from” and “Baggage surcharge may apply during peak periods on certain routes”, so it could be more, but I doubt it could be that much. I think it’s more likely there’s a confusion on the currency.

Years ago I was buying gas in Italy.  The attendant keyed in the price per liter as something like 123 instead of 1.23, and I only realized after the transaction was complete.

I think by the looks of it someone just made a mistake - $165 to $1650, thanks @Hilmar for the answer now the OP just needs to go back to the airline with the fare chart online and set his case. good luck and all the best!

Thanks everyone. Yes I was charged 42,200 bath which translate to $1625. I have proof of the receipt and credit card. I complained to scoot twice and were told it was the correct amount and scoot agent at the airport is correct.
